# CAShapeLayer with border at top and bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, uibezierpath, quartz-core, cashapelayer

I am creating a graph by using `CAShapeLayer` and `UIBezierPath`, it is working fine, But now i want to draw my line in multiple colors, like white in center and black at top and bottom. How can i achieve this? This is my code:

```
myLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
myLayer.path = pointPath;
myLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
myLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
myLayer.fillColor = nil;
myLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
[self.scroll.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
```

Comment: `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath`? Two paths with different width? **What have you tried** *and* **why didn't that work out for you?**